# Arch Linux で kernel 2.6.x は利用できるか

Tags: linux

Arch Linux でカーネルをダウングレードしたいと思っております。

Kernel 2.6.x は使えますでしょうか？

厳しいようでしたら、kernel 2.6.x が使えるディストリビューションを教えていただきたいです。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 2016-5-25リリースのCentOS6.8が2.6.32-642採用ですね([参考](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS#.E5.90.84.E3.83.90.E3.83.BC.E3.82.B8.E3.83.A7.E3.83.B3.E3.81.AE.E3.83.AA.E3.83.AA.E3.83.BC.E3.82.B9.E6.97.A5.E3.81.A8.E3.82.B5.E3.83.9D.E3.83.BC.E3.83.88.E6.9C.9F.E9.99.90), [RHEL](https://access.redhat.com/ja/node/16476))。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

arch linuxは古いバージョンはサポートしないというポリシーなので難しいと思います。別のディストリビューションを使うのが良いと思います。もしどうしても arch linux にこだわりたいければ kernel.orgでソースをダウンロードしてビルドするという方法も考えられます。幸いドキュメントがありますのでこちらを参考にされてはと思います。ただ試行錯誤は必用でしょうね。

[カーネル/コンパイル/伝統的な方法 - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinuxjp.org/index.php/%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%8D%E3%83%AB/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%91%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB/%E4%BC%9D%E7%B5%B1%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AA%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95)

2.6 カーネルのディストリビューションであればお好みのディストリビューションで少し古いものをFTPサイトなどからダウンロードすると良いと思います。

例）
* Ubuntu 11.04
* Debian 6 (squeeze)
* RHEL/Centos 6